# Как применяются классы private в Java?

Tags: java, классы

Как применяются приватные классы (`private`) в Java?

При каких условиях мы их применяем?

Comment: Они могут быть полезны внутри класса А, когда часть функционала хочется в класс В вынести, скрыв это от пользователей класса А.

Answer (score 1):

Не самый частый кейс но обычно они применяются когда нужно какой-то кусок логики вынести отдельно, но так чтоб он не был доступен снаружи.

Небольшой пример:

Например у вас есть какой-то класс который обрабатывается состояния. На вход он получает какие-то данные и должен на выходе дать вам ответ. Но каждое состояние вычисляется по своей собственной логике и это логика не очень проста. Так вот вы можете создать несколько приватных классов в каждом из которых будет своя логика вычисления, а уже в самом обработчике просто вызывать один из методов этих классов для вычисления состояния.

На практике используются они не часто, и в целом ничего не мешает вам вынести все это в отдельные методы. Но так вы можете разделить часть логики более явно.

Comment: а что случится плохого, если мы сделаем его паблик?

Comment: Ну если этот класс должны видеть другие классы, то ничего. Но если он предназначен только для внутренней логики то зачем делать его public? Это своего рода контракт, чтоб никто не использовал то, что скрыто в одном месте. Скажем вы разработали его только для работы внутри одного класса, но сделали public. Пришел второй разраб и использовал его в другом месте. А потом вы решили поменять логику класса для которого он был создан, но вы уже должна следить, чтоб не сломать те места где он еще используется